# Proxy-mitm certificate

Tags: instagram, sha256, man-in-the-middle

I found a 'Little proxy-mitm' certificate in the user section in android trusted certificates. Have I been compromised? the certificate expired sometime back. I have done private video calls over the Instagram app. Have i been compromised?

Comment: the certificate dated from 2020-21.

Comment: Also I mostly use my home wifi for this device and sometime personal hotspot. There is an app called 'catch the man in the middle' that shows me that SHA256 fingerprints do not match about which i wrote in another question, you can refer to that as well.